# Creating a timetable using PHP

Tags: php, ajax, timetable

I am going to create a little app using PHP that acts as a timetable. I am going to have it going from 9.00am to 5.00pm and through monday to friday.

I am still deciding how i want the timetable to function but have this idea though, the user mouses over a section of the timetable, when the user clicks that point, a new event booking window opens up and the user selects the event type and event duration and then saves.

Now, I was going to create a 1440 pixel wide table and then have have each hour have 180pixels and each minute of that hour taking up 3 pixels. How would you go about implementing such a thing, and by that i mean, how would you go about making the app so that it knows what time it is when a user clicks a certain portion of the timetable?

Im not asking for code or anything like that, I'm just wondering how more experienced developers would go about creating such a timetable because there are a few other ways i have thought about going about this problem but its always nice to hear other peoples ideas about how they would go about solving a problem.

Any ideas are welcomed,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used Google's Gmail Calendar app yet? It does something similar, but doesn't worry minute accuracy. Does your app require minute precision? Will 15 minutes be adequate? Using javascript (jquery comes to mind, personally) to detect clicks of block divs for each hour which trigger ajax/php event handlers seems like the way to go (at least thats how google seem's to have done it)...

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an existing solution:

1. first solution with [jquery](http://www.stefanoverna.com/log/create-astonishing-ical-like-calendars-with-jquery)
2. sec sol with [jquery](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/jQuery-Week-Calendar-An-Easy-to-Implement-Google-Calendar-like-jQuery-Calendar-Plugin.aspx)
3. [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/)
4. you could try GWT and create a [pure crossplatform JS solution](http://blog.marcokrikke.nl/index.php/2010/02/tu-delft-timetable-interface-user-test-feedback/)
5. [if you would use JSF](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_schedule.html)
6. if you would use wicket => [this](http://wicketstuff.org/maven/repository/org/wicketstuff/wicketstuff-calendar/) or [that](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/wicket-users/200710.mbox/%3C47021D97.6010605@jayway.dk%3E)
7. search engines are your friend ...

(I know some more Java desktops libs like [bizcal](http://sourceforge.net/project/screenshots.php?group_id=157010&ssid=62278))